# Why isn't my 2-column Pure CSS layout working?

Tags: html, css, meteor, stylus, yui-pure-css

I'm trying to create a simple [Meteor](http://www.meteor.com/) Web application, but am struggling already to produce a working 2 column layout defined via a [Pure responsive grid](http://purecss.io/grids). The problem is demonstrated in the below screenshot; the heading should be two columns on one line, not two (lines) and "Sidebar Content" should be in the column to the left of "Ace Editor Demo":

[image]

You may also visit the [live version](http://meteor-ace.meteor.com/) of my application to see the problem for yourself. Additionally, I've published the project on [github](https://github.com/aknuds1/meteor-ace).

It'd make me very happy if someone could point out why my intended 2 column layout isn't working as intended. I've tested with Chromium 28.0.1500.71 and Firefox 23.0.

## Code

### Styling

This is the application's style sheet (written in [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/)):

```
menu-background = #272F32
menu-color = #DAEAEF
padding-horizontal = 3em
padding-vertical = 1em
padding-top = 35px

.content
    border-radius: 10px
    margin-top 39px
    background-color white

    padding-left 0px
    padding-right 0px
    // padding-top padding-vertical
    padding-bottom padding-vertical

    .content-ribbon
        background-color white
        //padding-left padding-horizontal
        //padding-right padding-horizontal

    #sidebar
        padding-left: 20px
        padding-top: padding-top

    #editor-container
        padding-top: padding-top
        border-left: 1px solid
        padding-left: padding-horizontal
        height: 600px

        & > h1
            margin-top: 0

        .ace_editor
          width: 700px
          height: 500px

#menu
    background-color menu-background
    .pure-menu-heading
        //padding-left: 40px
        //padding-right: 7px
        // width: 170px
        color white

    li
        a
            color menu-color
            &:hover
                background-color rgb(51, 51, 51)

        &.pure-menu-selected
            a
                -webkit-box-shadow inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125)
                -moz-box-shadow inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125)
                box-shadow inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125)
                background-color: #111111
                color rgb(220, 220, 220)

footer
    //margin-top 5em
    margin-top 0px
    border-top 1px solid menu-background
    padding 1em
    color black
    text-align center
    font-size 80%
```

### HTML

The application's HTML, an Angular template (angular.html) and a partial (partials/home.html); you may notice the root div defines a Pure responsive grid (class `pure-g-r`), the columns are defined through classes `pure-u-1-5` (left column) and `pure-u-4-5` (right column):

#### angular.html

```
<div class="content pure-g-r" data-ng-controller="MeteorCtrl">
    <header class="pure-u-1">
        <nav id="menu" class="pure-menu pure-menu-open pure-menu-fixed pure-menu-horizontal">
            <div class="pure-u-1-5">
                <div class="pure-menu-heading">Meteor-Ace</div>
            </div>

            <ul class="pure-u-4-5">
                <li data-ng-repeat="menuItem in menuItems">
                    <a href="{{menuItem.address}}">{{menuItem.name}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <article id="content" class="pure-u-1">
        <div class="pure-g-r content-ribbon">
            <div class="pure-u-1">
                <div data-ng-view></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer class="pure-u-1">
            Made with the excellent <a href="http://meteor.com/">Meteor</a> framework and
            <a href="http://meteor.com/">AngularJS</a>. © 2013 Arve Knudsen
        </footer>
    </article>
</div>
```

#### partials/home.html

```
<div class="pure-u-1-5">
    <div id="sidebar">Sidebar Content</div>
</div>

<div class="pure-u-4-5">
    <div id="editor-container">
        <h1><a href="http://ace.c9.io/">Ace</a> Editor Demo</h1>

        <!--<div data-ui-ace></div>-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tested a little bit in Chrome Developer tools, and after moving the elements up a level and back in the document tree they are laid out correctly!? Very confusing... Maybe it's to do with Angular's manipulation of the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem was that I nested grid columns within columns (oops). The following HTML is rectified and doesn't exhibit any layout problems:

#### angular.html

```
<div class="content pure-g-r" data-ng-controller="MeteorCtrl">
    <header>
        <nav id="menu" class="pure-menu pure-menu-open pure-menu-fixed pure-menu-horizontal">
            <div class="pure-u-1-5">
                <div class="pure-menu-heading">Meteor-Ace</div>
            </div>

            <ul class="pure-u-4-5">
                <li data-ng-repeat="menuItem in menuItems">
                    <a href="{{menuItem.address}}">{{menuItem.name}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <article id="content">
        <div class="content-ribbon">
                <div data-ng-view></div>
        </div>
        <footer class="pure-u-1">
            Made with the excellent <a href="http://meteor.com/">Meteor</a> framework and
            <a href="http://meteor.com/">AngularJS</a>. © 2013 Arve Knudsen
        </footer>
    </article>
</div>
```

#### partials/home.html

```
<div class="pure-u-1-5">
    <div id="sidebar">Sidebar Content</div>
</div>

<div class="pure-u-4-5">
    <div id="editor-container">
        <h1><a href="http://ace.c9.io/">Ace</a> Editor Demo</h1>

        <div data-ui-ace></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be legit though? The columns have no margin/padding...but I'm seeing the same issue you were seeing.

Answer (score 0):

The two columns are divs so they need to be floating.

Try adding `float: left;` like so:

```
.pure-g-r [class *= "pure-u"] {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  float: left;
}
```

This is what I get when I add the float:

[image: Imgur]

Comment: I don't think they should be floats. If you look at [the pure grid documentation](http://purecss.io/grids/) you should see from the examples that columns are accomplished by making them inline-blocks (via class pure-u-*). I've also succeeded in creating a 2 column layout in a different (also very simple) application.

Comment: Then you must have some css missing or you elements are not properly classed

Comment: If you see my comment to my question I found that moving the elements back and forth in the DOM tree via Chromium dev tools made a difference (the layout works after doing so). Seems like some kind of bad state.